# Taking a credit card number and outputting the company name

Tags: java

need to get the card issuer along with the number, only outputs "Unknown".
(the bottom is just tester code).
am i trying to test the wrong variable, am i incorrectly using indexOf()?  please, any help would be appreciated

```
public class CreditCard 
{
    private String card_number;
    private boolean is_number;
    private String number_string = "";
    public String issuer_name = "";

    public CreditCard(String card_number)
    {
        this.card_number = card_number;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < card_number.length(); x++)
        {
            char y = card_number.charAt(x);
            is_number = Character.isDigit(y);
            if (is_number)
            {
                number_string += y;
            }

        }

        String s = number_string + " was issued by " + getIssuer();
        return s;
    }

    public void setIssuer(String issuer)
    {
        issuer_name = issuer;
    }

    public String getIssuer()
    {
        String issuer_Name;
        if (card_number.indexOf('4') == 0 && card_number.length() == 13 || card_number.length() == 16)
        {
            issuer_Name = "VISA";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 2 && number_string.length() == 14)
        {
            issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('5') == 2 && number_string.length() == 14)
        {
            issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('6') == 1 && card_number.length() == 14)
        {
            issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('8') == 1 && card_number.length() == 14)
        {
            issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('4') == 1 && card_number.length() == 15)
        {
            issuer_Name = "American Express";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('7') == 1 && card_number.length() == 15)
        {
            issuer_Name = "American Express";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('5') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('1') == 1 && card_number.length() == 16)
        {
            issuer_Name = "MasterCard";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('5') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('5') == 1 && card_number.length() == 16)
        {
            issuer_Name = "MasterCard";
        }
        if (card_number.indexOf('6') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('1') == 2 && number_string.indexOf('1') == 3 && number_string.length() == 16)
        {
            issuer_Name = "Discover";
        }
        else
        {
            issuer_Name = "Unknown";
        }
        return issuer_Name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(new CreditCard("42225-22222222"));
        System.out.println(new CreditCard("76009644571"));
        System.out.println(new CreditCard("50197170-10103742"));
        System.out.println(new CreditCard("6331101899890016"));
    }


}
```

Comment: It seems to be `Java`.

Comment: According to your program, the output could be only "*Discover*" or "*Unknown*". It's irrelevant whether previous conditions are satisfied or not, the last `if-else` overwrites the variable.

Comment: my bad, the tag automatically corrected it to javascript

Comment: By the way you shouldn't be mutating an object (changing its fields such as `number_string`) inside `toString`. (What happens if the method is called more than once?)

Comment: could you help me with the if-else tree?

Comment: I would advice not to hardcode this, but use third party software. Since credit card companies tend to be founded and get bankrupt, you will need to rewrite the program for every change where third party companies have a stronger "financial incentive" to modify their code...

Answer (score 1):

The if else clause would start something like

```
if (card_number.indexOf('4') == 0 && card_number.length() == 13 || card_number.length() == 16) {
    issuer_Name = "VISA";
} else if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 2 && number_string.length() == 14) {
    issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
} else if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('5') == 2 && number_string.length() == 14) {
    issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
} else if (card_number.indexOf('3') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('6') == 1 && card_number.length() == 14) {
    issuer_Name = "Diner's Club";
} else {
    issuer_Name = "Other";
}
```

Note I am not looking at the correctness of the algorithm, but you asked for how to do the if/else

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (card_number.indexOf('6') == 0 && card_number.indexOf('0') == 1 && card_number.indexOf('1') == 2 && number_string.indexOf('1') == 3 && number_string.length() == 16)
    {
        issuer_Name = "Discover";
    }
    else
    {
        issuer_Name = "Unknown";
    }
```

Check this Code.
If a card issuer is not Discover, the output ALWAYS "Unknow"

```
if (true) {
  n=1; 
}
if (true) { 
  n=2; 
}
if (true) { 
  n=3;
}
else {
 n=0;
}
```

The n is either 3 or 0, cannot be 1 or 2. 
Because the last if-else will override the n

You can fix this issue by changing "if" to "else if"